# What is this illustration portraying?

Tags: soviet-union, political-history, communism

While doing my presentation I have come across this illustration titles "Downfall of the Soviet Union". I am, however, unable to determine, who are the people on this illustration and what is it trying to represent. I am asking for analysis of the photo; from who is depicted to what is it showing.

[image]

Comment: The image seems to be used as part of the assessment in the course _Crisis and Conflict: From a World War to a Cold War_ by Marshall Cavendish Education.  It may have been created specifically for that assessment.

Answer (score 9):

As @sempaiscuba said in the comments, this image was used in a presentation for the course  Crisis and Conflict: From a World War to a Cold War by Marshall Cavendish Education.

You can find the presentation here: https://slideplayer.com/slide/6620291/

The notes to this particular slide explain the intended message behind this image:

> Using this illustration, identify the reasons behind the failure of the Communist system:
>
> - Poor transport and distribution system: The Soviet Union’s transport system did not function effectively. The breakdown of trains and trucks meant that supplies were not being transported in a timely or reliable manner. Factories could not be sure when their materials would be delivered and when their products would be sent to customers. Shopkeepers did not know when they would receive their supplies.
> - Factories were not improved: Factories were not well-maintained. While the Soviets felt that it was important to improve their military technology, they neglected to also improve technology in civilian areas.
> - Alcoholism made workers less efficient: Productivity fell because many workers were not doing their jobs properly as a result of drinking too much. Some workers did not even turn up for work because they were too drunk.
> - There was widespread corruption in the Soviet Union. Many low-level officials would try to increase their income by taking bribes and high-ranking officials were in a position to become wealthy by using state resources for their own benefit.

So, this is not a caricature of a particular event, this is an illustration that combines several points in a history lesson.